# Displaying the number of rows in an uploaded data file using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display the number of rows in an uploaded data file. What I am getting as output though is 'data1'. Can somebody assist in getting the number of rows in a data file?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
sidebarPanel(
fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',accept =   c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values','text/tab-separated-values','text/plain','.csv','.tsv')),
checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'),'Comma'),
radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'Double Quote'),
actionButton("Load", "Load the File"),width = 3),

mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("my_output_data"))
)
```

**server.R**

```
server = function(input, output) {

data1 <- reactive({
if(input$Load == 0){return()}
inFile <- input$file1
if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

isolate({ 
  input$Load
  my_data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
  my_data_size <- nrow(my_data)
})
my_data_size
})

output$my_output_data <- renderPrint({data1})

}
```

Answer (score 2):

So data1 is actually a reactive function. So in the renderPrint({}), change to:

```
output$my_output_data <- renderPrint({data1()})
```

With the parentheses you're running the function and getting the output. Without the parentheses, you're just getting the gut of the function object itself, not it's output.

Hope this helps. I tested this on my end with a sample dataset and it works.